# Confused by Ruby float truncate

Tags: ruby, floating-point

The truncate method on Float apparently truncates the float to an integer. So what's going on here:

```
>> 14820.truncate
=> 14820
>> (148.2 * 100)
=> 14820.0
>> 14820.0.truncate
=> 14820
>> (148.2 * 100).truncate
=> 14819
```

why doesn't the last calculation output 14820 as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floating point rounding error, which is not related to `truncate`. E.g. try this

```
 (148.2 * 100) < 14820
```

It returns `true`. Figuratively speaking, you get number `148.199999999` instead of `148.2`, because `148.2` can't be represented *exactly* in a floating point number.

Answer (score 3):

The result of `148.2 * 100` is likely not exactly 14820 but is rather something slightly less than that value due to floating point error.  Thus, it would truncate to 14819.

You can see the value with this:

```
>sprintf("%.19f", 148.2*100)
=> "14819.9999999999981810106"
```

Answer (score 0):

As said above, this is floating point rounding error. I'll add that Ruby has buit-in class [Rational](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Rational.html), which can represent rational fractions without such a drawback, so you may want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered rounding instead of truncating?